# Shibboleth Service Provider - How to populate REMOTE_USER variable

Tags: adfs, shibboleth

Environment: Linux / Apache / Shibboleth SP 2.6

I'm looking for some help with the mapping I would need to do in order to populate the REMOTE_USER variable. I'm not sure what exactly I need to add to the attribute-map.xml file in order to make that happen.

In the shibboleth2.xml file, we have ..

```
<ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://tap-jmistst-rv02.usmstest.doj.gov/shibboleth"
                     REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
                     cipherSuites="ECDHE+AESGCM:ECDHE:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXPORT:!RC4:!SHA:!SSLv2">
```

What I don't understand is what I need to put in the attribute-map.xml file specifically in order to map the value of NameID  to REMOTE_USER

When I hit my application URL, it does redirect to ADFS, and then I see that NameID is populated with my username in the Shibboleth transaction.log. What I'm trying to do is get REMOTE_USER set with that value.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REMOTE_USER attribute in the ApplicationDefaults element above denotes a list of decoded attributes (in order of preference)  that the SP will use to populate Apache's REMOTE_USER.

In order to populate this with the Assertion NameID, you need first to decode this into an attribute ( named persistent-id here but feel free to change it) with

```
<Attribute name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" id="persistent-id">
    <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="NameIDAttributeDecoder" formatter="$NameQualifier!$SPNameQualifier!$Name" defaultQualifiers="true"/>
</Attribute>
```

and then assign it to REMOTE_USER with

```
REMOTE_USER="persistent-id"
```

In your

```
<ApplicationDefaults>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Yiannis, much appreciated. That's what I thought the answer was, but it still doesn't work for me. I'll check my configuration from top to bottom to try to find out why REMOTE_USER still is not getting populated.

Comment: You can try the following :
* Use FF [SAML Tracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) plugin to see the SAML Response as it is being delivered to your SP and verify the NameID is there in the Subject

* Check your transaction.log to see if the NameID is mapped to persistent-id (alt. visit https://YOURFQDN/Shibboleth.sso/Session

* Use a simple python/jsp/php script to print apache headers and see what is populated

Comment: Thanks again Yiannis. I got frustrated and moved on to mod_auth_mellon, but I might be back if I don't have better luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

To get REMOTE_USER parameter populated in Linux (CentOS and RHEL 6 and 7), configure apache with mod_auth_ntlm_winbind. Then you can pass the parameter to your application.

To configure mod_auth_ntlm_winbind, refer: https://hemakhema.blogspot.ae/2017/07/enable-sso-login-in-linux.html